# List of Actions for specific controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of controller names and would then have a list of all actions in a given controller (name, GUID).

The list of all controllers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151841/asp-net-mvc-programatically-get-a-list-of-controllers).

I was also reading [List all the actions on a controller with specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358170/asp-net-mvc-list-all-the-actions-on-a-controller-with-specific-attribute) which would match for my purposes as I also need actions with specific attributes. But I have only the name / GUID of the selected controller, not the object itself.

My scenario: the user selects a controller (cascading dropdown-list) and then actions from this controller to configure some access (and links). Therefore I need only the actions that have a custom attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can continue using Reflection just like you did to get the Types in your assembly that inherit from Controller. Once you have the Type, you can enumerate the methods:

```
foreach(MethodInfo method in myContollerType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public  | BindingFlags.Instance))
{

}
```

And, then for each method, you can get all the custom attributes:

```
foreach (var attribute in method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttributeType),false))
{

}
```