# Scan for all actions in the site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, navigation

How do I create action links for all actions in the site?
I want to put those action links into a menu system.

I was hoping I can do something like

```
foreach controller in controllers {
    foreach action in controller{
        stringbuilder.writeline(
            "<li>"+actionlink(menu, action, controller)+"<li>"
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
var controllers = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller))).ToList();
var controlList = controllers.Select(controller =>
                                     new
                                     {
                                         Actions = GetActions(controller),
                                         Name = controller.Name,
                                     }).ToList();
```

The method `GetActions` as follows:

```
public static List<String> GetActions(Type controller)
{
    // List of links
    var items = new List<String>();

    // Get a descriptor of this controller
    var controllerDesc = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller);

    // Look at each action in the controller
    foreach (var action in controllerDesc.GetCanonicalActions())
    {
        // Get any attributes (filters) on the action
        var attributes = action.GetCustomAttributes(false);

        // Look at each attribute
        var validAction =
            attributes.All(filter => !(filter is HttpPostAttribute) && !(filter is ChildActionOnlyAttribute));

        // Add the action to the list if it's "valid"
        if (validAction)
           items.Add(action.ActionName);
    }
    return items;
}
```

If you need a menu system checkout the [MVC Sitemap Provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), it will give you absolute control on what to render depending on the roles you've defined on your membership implementation.

Comment: I've looked at the provider, maybe i need to look a little more, but it looks like I need to define the menus through xml?

Comment: Yes, you would have to define the menus using XML. But you can use the code I provided to get the initial list (you still need to define which roles can access which action anyways)

Comment: We have a custom permissions based authorization that allows the users to define that. Its a multi tenant system, so it was either going to have to be table based or conventions based. We trying to get the latter working.

Comment: That works, but only if I change out Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() with Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

Answer (score 0):

Here is approach how get all actions from controller [Asp.net Mvc: List all the actions on a controller with specific attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358170/asp-net-mvc-list-all-the-actions-on-a-controller-with-specific-attribute) or [Accessing the list of Controllers/Actions in an ASP.NET MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790464/accessing-the-list-of-controllers-actions-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
For achieving your goal you should find all controllers in your project with `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()` and filter only sub classes of `ControllerBase` and for each controller call `new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(typeof(TController)).GetCanonicalActions()` from 2nd link.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these out on Monday.

Comment: Those posts only work on the current controller. The post by ahmed is more comprehensive, so I'll mark that as the answer.